# Proteactor- jasmine - How to execute one js file inside another js

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Suppose have A.js file with 10 it blocks, now in middle of exuction say in 6th it block need to execute another more js file say B.js

Comment: I understood what you want to achieve, and most likely it's not possible. But I can't even think of a possible use case for doing this. If you could explain why you want to do so in the first place I may help you find a workaroud

Comment: I agree with Sergey here, basically you cannot put an `it` block inside another `it`. Or a `describe` inside an `it` block. Maybe explain to us why you want to do this, so we can offer better help

Comment: I have 2 js files[A.js with some it blocks, B.js with some it block as individual test suite]. Now in A.js, one of the it block requires as pre-condition should execute all flow[all it blocks] which are mentioned in B.js. Instead again pasting all it blocks from B.js to A.js it block, is there any way to handle it. This is what my current scenario. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you mean, but you could have several `describe` blocks with their `it` blocks inside of them.

```
describe('Main file', () => {
    describe('Describe A', () => {
        it('some it block from A', async () => {
            // code here
        });
    });

    describe('Describe B', () => {
        it('some it block from B', async () => {
            // code here
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Yes that is not what i am expecting.

Comment: maybe you can find this link useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830202/nested-it-in-protractor-jasmine  
took me 2 secs to google

Comment: thanks for reply. Yes that is not what i am expecting.

Scenario : 

A.js :
describe('Main file', () => {   
 it('some it block1', async () => {
  // code here
 });
 
 it('some it block2', async () => {
  // code here
 });
 
 it('some it block3', async () => {
  
 });
}); 


B.js :
describe('Main file', () => {   
 it('some it block1', async () => {
  // code here
 });
 
 it('some it block2', async () => {
  // code here
 });
 
 it('some it block3', async () => {
  //In this it block I wan to execute A.js
 });
});