# Mocha - How to have multiply it functions inside a it function

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, mocha.js, chai

So I have been trying to figure out if its possible to do something like this.

```
it('Check for remove button', function () {
    element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined')).getText().then(function (text) {
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            console.log(i) //Prints 0 1 2

            it('Click remove button - ' + i + '/3', function (done) {
                console.log("Hello") //Never prints
                browser.driver
                    .then(() => utils.click(detailsSpecs.getRemoveButton()))
                    .then(() => done());
                });

            it('Wait for fading button to be gone', function (done) {
                console.log("World")  //Never prints
                setTimeout(function () {
                    done();
                }, 1000);
            });
        };
    });
});
```

As you can see I have a it function where it represent the issue (Check how many elements there are) and then I have two **it** functions inside the **it** itself. Which one clicks and the second one is timed out but my problem is that it doesn't want to enter any of those **it** inside the for loop however the for loop work itself and it seems like I am not able to have multiple **it** inside a **it** function.

I wonder how I am able to solve it - if its possible to do something like this?

Comment: Probably you are missing `done` param in your first `it`.

Comment: Where should it be in that case? @elhoucine

Comment: you can't do nested `it` but you could do what described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802275/9150146

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Oh alright, I will look at that but I am not sure how I would be able to have a it function that checks how many elments.all.length and then use that it value to a for loop for another nested it, if you know what I mean?

Comment: ^ Correct. I have no idea how to close this thread. Should I delete or vote as close?