# Protractor : Can I have two describe block in one spec file?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

```
describe('describe 1', function () {

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await browser.sleep(3000);
    await browser.navigate().to(URL);   
  });

  it('Edit Client', async () => {
    await browser.wait(until.presenceOf(SpadesPageObj.ClientEdit), 50000, 'Client Edit');
    await SpadesPageObj.ClientEdit.click();
  });

})

describe('describe 2', function () {

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await browser.sleep(3000);
    await browser.navigate().to(URL);

  })
    it('Edit Client', async () => {
    await browser.wait(until.presenceOf(SpadesPageObj.ClientEdit), 50000, 'Client Edit');
    await SpadesPageObj.ClientEdit.click();
  });

})
```

Is the above code correct?
**Can I have two describe block in one spec file?**
My problem is I do not want to run **beforeEach** for all the **IT blocks** so I created a two describe, Is there any workaround in which I can skip **beforeEach** for some of the test cases?

I tried to run the above code and the only 1st describe runs and it skips the 2nd describe.

Comment: it worked for me too add your cofig fiel and console out put where you see only one describe ran7

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that. and you can also do nested describes (one inside another) https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802275/9150146

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not looking for this.
I want to know that  --
**Is there any workaround in which I can skip beforeEach for some of the test cases?**
or 
**Can I use two describe block in one spec file ?**

Comment: this is why my answer to you second question in the comment (or your overall post's header) was `yes you can do that`

Comment: I tried to run the code and only 1st describe runs and it skips the 2nd describe.

Comment: that weird. it most certainly works. I just double checked it locally. What's your console output? any errors?

Comment: `await browser.navigate().to(URL);` command doesn't exist as far as I know. Use `browser.get()`

Comment: No errors - It only executes the first describe!

Comment: as I mentioned, update you code to use browser.get

Comment: @sergrey -- I am not getting any error due to .navigate().to(URL) my code works fine!!

Comment: here is what you can do, remove all protractor commands and paste console.log instead. If it works, that would mean you can have multiple describes, and that something is wrong with the code. Or otherwise

Comment: sure will try it