# How to skip dependent feature file when parent feature file fails in protractor cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I have 5 test scenarios in my 5 different feature files.
TC-1
TC-2
TC-3
TC-4
TC-5
TC-3&TC-4 are dependent test cases when test scenario TC-3 failed automatically TC-4 should skip and TC-5 should execute how we can achieve this in cucumber any suggestions
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I never worked with cucumber closely, but I found out it's not possible in jasmine and pytest. So I assume this is how all test frameworks work.

The problem is that both of these^ build a queue of tests to execute before the browser started. And you can't modify it based on a runtime results.

see this answer for jasmine, and see if you can apply this approach to cucumber [Nested it in Protractor/Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830202/nested-it-in-protractor-jasmine/50802275#50802275)